# Extracting sublist entries prior to a marker

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list from which I would like to extract sublists:

```
lis = {{a,X,b},{c,d,e,X,f},{h,j,X}}
```

giving:

```
res = {{a},{c,d,e},{h,j}}
```

i.e., deleting each `X` and its following elements from each sublist.  Likely asked and answered; any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you could make `Thanks` `Listable` and save yourself the `/@` :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `ReplaceAll` with an appropriate pattern in such cases

```
{{a, X, b}, {c, d, e, X, f}, {h, j, X}} /. {begin___, X, end___} :> {begin}
```

Note the use of named patterns of the `BlankNullSequence` variety that can stand for any sequence of zero or more expressions

Comment: This is one elegant answer! beautiful!

Answer (score 13):

```
lis = {{a, X, b}, {c, d, e, X, f}, {h, j, X}};
TakeWhile[#, # =!= X &] & /@ lis
```

> {{a},{c,d,e},{h,j}}

---

From comment by Mr. [J.M](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)

```
First[Split[#, #2 =!= X &]] & /@ lis
```

Comment: In the same vein: `First[Split[#, #2 =!= X &]] & /@ lis`

Comment: @J.M. Maybe it deserve as a answer. :)

Comment: I'd prefer you edit your answer instead, as it is too similar to yours.

Answer (score 11):

Using [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html)

```
lis = {{a, X, b}, {c, d, e, X, f}, {h, j, X}};

#[[1 ;; Position[#, X][[1, 1]] - 1]] & /@ lis

(*  {{a}, {c, d, e}, {h, j}}  *)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this one assumes that each sublist *does* contain an `X`.

Answer (score 4):

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
lis = {{a, X, b}, {c, d, e, X, f}, {h, j, X}, {X, n, o}}

SequenceReplace[#, {a___, X, b___} :> a] & /@ lis
```

> {{a}, {c, d, e}, {h, j}, {}}

---

If lists without an `X` need to be ignored, then it is better to execute:

```
DeleteCases[lis, _?(FreeQ[#, X] &)]
```

prior to running the modified list through the `SequenceReplace` command.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a, X, b}, {c, d, e, X, f}, {h, j, X}};

Map[SequenceSplit[#, {X}] &, list][[All, 1]]
```

{{a}, {c, d, e}, {h, j}}

```
MapThread[Take, {list, Position[list, X][[All, 2]] - 1}]
```

{{a}, {c, d, e}, {h, j}}

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `MapThread`, `Position` and `Span`:

```
list = {{a, X, b}, {c, d, e, X, f}, {h, j, X}};

MapThread[#1[[#2]] &, {lis, Span[# - 1] & /@ Flatten[Position[#, X] & /@ lis]}]

(*{{a}, {c, d, e}, {h, j}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[#, {a___, X, b___} :> a] & /@ lis

(*{{a}, {c, d, e}, {h, j}}*)
```